# How to make Rightarrow with stopper

Tags: math-mode, symbols, amsmath, relation-symbols

The symbol `\Rrightarrow` produces an implication with three lines; the symbol `\Mapsto` produces an implication with two lines *and* a "stopper" (a vertical line which marks the beginning of the implication).

How can I add a stopper to `\Rrightarrow` to produce a three-line implication "with a beginning"? If any clarification is needed, I will gladly provide an example picture.

Thank you!

Comment: Where do you get `\Rrightarrow` from? Can you make a short example of code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build a symbol by adding a vertical line before a `\Rrightarrow`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\makeatletter
\newlength{\arrowdepth}
\newlength{\arrowheight}
\newcommand*{\Mmapsto}{%
    \settodepth{\arrowdepth}{$\Rrightarrow$}
    \settoheight{\arrowheight}{$\Rrightarrow$}
    \addtolength{\arrowheight}{\arrowdepth}
    \mathrel{%
        \rule[-\arrowdepth]{\fontdimen8\textfont 3}{\arrowheight}%
        \mkern-1.5mu%
        {\Rrightarrow}%
    }%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\(A \Rrightarrow B\)

\(A \Mmapsto B\)
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can fake it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,pict2e}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\Mmapsto}{}{%
  \mathrel{\mathpalette\Mmapstochar@\Rrightarrow}%
  \Rrightarrow
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\Mapsto}{}{%
  \mathrel{\mathpalette\Mmapstochar@\Rightarrow}%
  \Rightarrow
}

\newcommand{\Mmapstochar@}[2]{%
  \vcenter{%
    \sbox\z@{$#1#2$}%
    \setlength{\unitlength}{1.8\dimexpr\Mmapstochar@ht{#1}+\dp\z@\relax}
    \hbox to \z@{%
      $\m@th#1\mkern1.3mu\nonscript\mkern-0.3mu$%
      \Mmapstochar@thickness{#1}%
      \begin{picture}(0,1)
      \roundcap
      \Line(0,0)(0,1)
      \end{picture}\hss
    }%
  }%
}

\newcommand{\Mmapstochar@ht}[1]{%
  \fontdimen22
    \ifx#1\displaystyle\textfont\else
    \ifx#1\textstyle\textfont\else
    \ifx#1\scriptstyle\scriptfont\else
    \scriptscriptfont\fi\fi\fi 2
}

\newcommand{\Mmapstochar@thickness}[1]{%
  \linethickness{%
    \fontdimen8
      \ifx#1\displaystyle\textfont\else
      \ifx#1\textstyle\textfont\else
      \ifx#1\scriptstyle\scriptfont\else
      \scriptscriptfont\fi\fi\fi 3
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$A\Rrightarrow B \Rightarrow C$

$A\Mmapsto B \Mapsto C$

$\scriptstyle A\Mmapsto B \Mapsto C$

$\scriptscriptstyle A\Mmapsto B \Mapsto C$

\end{document}
```

Not perfect in `\scriptscriptstyle`, but I guess you're not going that deep.

Remember to load `fixcmex` if you use `lmodern`. Other symbol fonts than `ammsymb` may need some tweaking.

[image]